# Bootstrap Less Out of stack space Error v3

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am using ASP.NET Web forms 4.0 and receiving the following error and wondering if anyone can help me resolve it?

```
During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/test/Content/BootstrapOverride.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred. 
See more details:

Error type: Syntax
Message: Out of stack space
File: /test/Content/bootstrap/variables.less

[AssetTranslationException: During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/test/Content/BootstrapOverride.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred. 
See more details:

Error type: Syntax
Message: Out of stack space
File: /test/Content/bootstrap/variables.less
]
   BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.InnerTranslate(IAsset asset, LessCompiler lessCompiler, Boolean enableNativeMinification) +1005
   BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IList`1 assets) +524
   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Translate(IList`1 assets, Boolean isDebugMode) +126
   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.CssTransformer.Transform(IList`1 assets, BundleResponse bundleResponse, VirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider, HttpContextBase httpContext, Boolean isDebugMode) +122
   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response, Boolean isDebugMode) +425
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +266
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +65
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +253
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +270
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +34
   ASP.skinned_master.__RenderStyles(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in D:\Inetpub\Apps\test\Skinned.Master:14
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +27
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +48
   ASP.skinned_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in D:\Inetpub\Apps\test\Skinned.Master:28
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.RenderPageInAjaxMode(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control page) +1056
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5290
```

--Answer----
This issue was eventually resolved by setting the app pool to use 32 bit mode rather than 64 bit mode.

Comment: were you ever able to find a resolution to this issue?  I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when you have a recursive import, you end up blowing out the stack allocating less variables. Check your import files to make sure that one of the files you are importing are not referencing each other (specifically `variables.less` and `BootstrapOverride.less`)

*edited*

To answer your comment, I dont know how you have your imports structured, it would be helpful to see you imports in bootstrapoverride, variables, and bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap.less is only referenced once in the boostrapoverride.less but if i remove all the content in the variables.less, then it starts complaining about other less files and it's going on so and so on.